# prntscrn button doesn't work in Ubuntu 16.04 (worked fine in 14.04)

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys

I'm running 16.04 on an HP laptop. In 14.04, the `prntscrn` button worked as intended (pressing it took a screenshot of the whole screen, pressing `shift + prntscrn` took a partial screenshot of a selected area, etc.). Ever since upgrading to 16.04, I can't get it to work *at all*.

All of the shortcuts are set correctly and everything.

`gnome-screenshot` *is* installed, and works if I type it into the terminal.

`xev` shows this for press + release of the `prntscrn` button:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x2c2, subw 0x0, time 5325568, (-443,285), root:(346,337),
    state 0x10, keycode 218 (keysym 0xff61, Print), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 107
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x2c2, subw 0x0, time 5325759, (-443,285), root:(346,337),
    state 0x10, keycode 218 (keysym 0xff61, Print), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 107
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

For comparison, it shows this for the press + release of the `F12` button (which works well):

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x2c2, subw 0x0, time 5433196, (-509,256), root:(280,308),
    state 0x10, keycode 96 (keysym 0xffc9, F12), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x2c2, subw 0x0, time 5433406, (-509,256), root:(280,308),
    state 0x10, keycode 96 (keysym 0xffc9, F12), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screenshot/+bug/1295994/comments/25):

> As I noticed from xev output pressing prt sc on HP Pavilion returns two different codes: 218(the key's code itself) and XKeysymToKeycode returns 107.
>
> I looked at key mapping with xmodmap -pke and noticed that there's binding 107 to Print action but there's no binding for 218 keycode. So I just add binding for keycode 218:
>
> `xmodmap -e "keycode 218 = Print"`
>
> and then removed binding from 107 keycode
>
> `xmodmap -e "keycode 107 = "`
>
> After that everything have started working just fine.
> Hope I helped someone.